# Erro SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

Tags: java, android, sqlite, async

```
public ArrayList<String> addMigracaoCadIndividual(String QUERY){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return null;
}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:285)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
>           at br.com.itconect.sisam.BancoDandos.addMigracaoCadIndividual(BancoDandos.java:565)
>           at br.com.itconect.sisam.RetornoServidor.recebeResposta(RetornoServidor.java:13)
>           at br.com.itconect.sisam.EnviarDadosPhp.onPostExecute(EnviarDadosPhp.java:70)
>           at br.com.itconect.sisam.EnviarDadosPhp.onPostExecute(EnviarDadosPhp.java:14)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: sempre que executo addMigracaoCadIndividual(s) ele da essas msg de erro

Answer (score 1):

Lógico, você está retornando `null`. A parte do código que chama `addMigracaoCadIndividual(s)` deve estar esperando alguma coisa que não seja `null` (uma `ArrayList` de `Strings`, no caso).

Tente assim:

```
public ArrayList<String> addMigracaoCadIndividual(String QUERY){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> resultado = new ArrayList<>();
    // Pegue Strings do banco e coloque na ArrayList aqui.
    // Pesquise por exemplos de SQLite para Android no Google.
    resultado.add("Este é só um exemplo");
    return resultado;
}
```